# Nodemon is not working in Docker environment

Tags: node.js, docker, nodemon, fig, node-supervisor

I'm using Docker with fig to build NodeJS dev-env.

While I using nodemon to watch the server.js, changing server.js won't restart the server.

```
CMD ["nodemon", "/nodeapp/server.js"]
```

But while I changed from nodemon to supervisor, then it worked!

```
CMD ["supervisor", "/nodeapp/server.js"]
```

Does anyone know where the problem is?

More informations are below:

---

My fig folder structure:

```
app/server.js
    package.json
    node_modules/
fig.yml
Dockerfile
```

fig.yml:

```
nodejs:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
```

Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# NVM
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash - && \
  apt-get install -y nodejs

VOLUME ./app:/nodeapp
WORKDIR /nodeapp

RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh && \
  npm install -g nodemon mocha supervisor
CMD ["nodemon", "/nodeapp/server.js"]
```

Server.js: (sample code from NodeJS website)

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello 12\n');
}).listen(8080);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first up - `VOLUME ./app:/nodeapp` does not do what you want - you're creating a directory in the image called `/app:/nodeapp` - and so at no point is the server.js file getting onto your image.

test using `docker run --rm -it yourimagename ls -la`

changing your Dockerfile to

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install -yq curl
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# NVM
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash - && \
  apt-get install -y nodejs

#VOLUME ./app:/nodeapp
ADD     app /nodeapp
WORKDIR /nodeapp

RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh && \
  npm install -g nodemon mocha supervisor
CMD ["nodemon", "/nodeapp/server.js"]
```

gets me:

```
mini:nodaemon sven$ docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 nodaemon     
2 Dec 02:27:52 - [nodemon] v1.2.1
2 Dec 02:27:52 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
2 Dec 02:27:52 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
2 Dec 02:27:52 - [nodemon] starting `node /nodeapp/server.js`
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There's a mistake in my Dockerfile.
Actually, what I want is:
My nodejs env is in the Docker container. 
While I change my code in the project folder on my host OS, the container will detect the changed file and then restart the server.js automatically. 
It's my mistake that I didn't describe my problem well.
Can Docker do that?

Answer (score 63):

There is a special option `--legacy-watch` to enable nodemon's legacy watching mode:

```bash
nodemon --legacy-watch --watch ./your/files/here --exec "npm run some-command"
```

Here is the respective nodemon [docs](https://github.com/remy/nodemon?tab=readme-ov-file#application-isnt-restarting) as @Jonathan pointed out in comments and the Docker [issue](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1802).

Comment: This is apparently the recommended way to get nodemon working inside a Docker container https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting

Comment: `-L` shorthand, but this also worked for me

Comment: Really simple and great solution! Props!

Comment: That is fucking amazing solution, that is really working in my docker container node js server

Answer (score 6):

This is how I do it:

You will need nodemon version 1.3.0-5 for this (`npm i -g nodemon@dev`)

.dockerignore:

```
node_modules/*
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:0.10

WORKDIR /nodeapp
ADD ./package.json /nodeapp/package.json
RUN npm install --production

ADD ./app /nodeapp/app

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["node", ".", "--production"]
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "fig-nodemon",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./app/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "nodemon": "fig up -d && fig run nodejs npm i --development && nodemon -x \"fig kill nodejs && fig build nodejs && fig start nodejs && fig logs nodejs\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

fig.yml:

```
nodejs:
  build: .
  command: node . --development
  volumes:
    - ./app:/nodeapp/app
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
```

app/server.js:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello 13\n');
}).listen(8080);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

then I run `npm run nodemon` to get started.

Answer (score 3):

The server will restart automatically after save if you put the following code in the package.json file:

```
"nodemonConfig": {
    "legacyWatch": true
}
```

This is also mentioned [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting).

Answer (score 1):

Change your backend package.json file nodemon script to below.
More info https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting

> "start": "nodemon -L index.js --ignore './tests'"

Answer (score 1):

There is a special option for node, it works in containers.

```
node --watch-path=/app server.js
```

node -version 18.0.0+