# Setting up the docker-compose volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volumes

I don't know what's wrong with my `docker-compose`, I'm trying to implement volume to constantly updating the app inside the container while working on it on the host with the nodemon, but it doesn't work. I have been fighting with it almost the whole day, but I can't see what is wrong.

```
FROM node:12.18.4
WORKDIR /usr/src/youtube-clone-app
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    youtube-clone-app:
        build: ./
        container_name: server
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        volumes:
            - ./:/usr/src/youtube-clone-app
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js docker container not updating to changes in volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60192208/node-js-docker-container-not-updating-to-changes-in-volume)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't make nodemon to restart every time I update the file on the host machine

Comment: What does your npm start script look like?

Comment: `"start": "nodemon index.js"`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to understand exactly what you need, but try this:

```
FROM node:12.18.4
WORKDIR /usr/src/youtube-clone-app
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./
CMD ["nodemon", "start"]
```

Note `CMD ["nodemon", "start"]` instead of `CMD ["npm", "start"]`. If necessary, try to replace `start` with your node app script, e.g. `./server.js`. Make sure `nodemon` is in your `package.json`. Additionally, add a context to your `docker-compose` build option.

Answer (score 0):

I tried recreating your setup as much as I could from you question and it works. The problem is probably with either volume or how you run nodemon.

You can try debugging the problem like so:

1. Remove `CMD [ "npm", "start" ]` from `Dockerfile`
2. Add `tty: true` to `youtube-clone-app` service in Docker Compose (like in my example below)
3. Run the container with Docker Compose `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate` (options `--build --force-recreate` rebuild the image).
4. Run `bash` in container with `docker-compose exec youtube-clone-app bash`
5. In bash, list files with `ls` to see if all necessary files are there.
6. Print the contents of a file you are trying to update with `cat <file>`, update the file on your host, and print it again to see if the contents are updated.
7. Run nodemon manually in bash with `nodemon index.js` (or some other file that is your entrypoint)

If there is a missing file in step 5 or contents of a file are not updated in step 6, it is probably an issue with volume mount.

In step 7 you can test which command works - it might be that `CMD [ "npm", "start" ]` is the problem.

Here is my test setup that works:

```
// index.js
console.log("Hello")
```

```
# docker-compose.yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
    youtube-clone-app:
        build: ./
        container_name: server
        volumes:
            - ./:/usr/src/youtube-clone-app
        tty: true # Keep container running even if there is no CMD/ENTRYPOINT
```

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:12.18.4
WORKDIR /usr/src/youtube-clone-app
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install
ENTRYPOINT ["npx", "nodemon", "index.js"] # If nodemon is installed globally, remove the "npx" argument
```

If you run this test setup with `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate` you should see `Hello` printed in the terminal. When you change `index.js` and save it, it should print whatever you changed it to.

Also, prefer `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD`. For more info check out the [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile) question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can replace steps 1-4 with `docker-compose run youtube-clone-app bash`, without modifying any of the application files – but only if you _don't_ change `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT`.  This is one of a couple of reasons I actively prefer `CMD` over `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: In step 6 the file is updating, but when I type the last step I get the error  `bash: nodemon: command not found`, but when I do `npm start` or `npx nodemon index.js` the nodemon is launching, but still, I don't get what I want. Updating the file on the host machine restarts the nodemon, but it doesn't happen in the docker and this is what I want. So, if the file is updated and docker knows about it because it can be checked with `cat <file>` I don't know why it is not restarting.

Comment: I found this GitHub issue https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1447, try some of their propsed solutions. A lot commented that adding a `-L` flag (legacy watch) fixes the problem. And if that doesn't work, try different versions of the node image and the nodemon dependency.

Comment: @touchmarine you've got it! But I have found another solution, much less preferred, however, it's working. When I installed the remote WSL in VSCode, as described here [remote WSL2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl), it started to work. But yours is working as I wanted, on my normal Win10 system. Thank you!