# Nodemon not refreshing its content within Docker

Tags: docker, nodemon

Despite there are a lot of Q/A on internet I couldn't find anything that would fix me the issue that running a simple `express` js app, won't refresh on changes when running it inside Docker.

Here's my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.11
WORKDIR /var/be_core
VOLUME /var/be_core
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.9'
volumes:
  be_core_volume:

services:
  be_server_core:
    ports:
      - "9000:3000"
    image: jeko/be_server_core
    environment:
      - BE_SERVER_CORE_PORT=3000
    volumes:
      - "be_core_volume:/var/be_core"
```

The js server, really simple:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello world");
});

const PORT = process.env.BE_SERVER_CORE_PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Core server running on internal port : ${PORT}`);
});
```

the command `npm start` simply run that

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon -L ./server.js"
}
```

If I run the server as a *stand alone* process (not within a docker container) it works perfectly.
using the command `docker-compose up` - instead - seems to works fine, since it starts everything, but when changing something in the `server.js` file, it doesn't refresh.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting your application code with a Docker named volume.

`volumes:` can mount two things, either a directory from the host system (a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)) or storage managed by Docker (a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)).  When the part on the left-hand side of the colon is just a name, it's mounting a named volume.

Named volumes have some odd behavior when you mount a volume over a directory that has content in the image.  *The first time only* when you run the container, the contents of the image are copied to the volume.  Every time after that, though, the (old) contents of the volume take precedence, even if the underlying image is updated.  So with your setup not only is it not mounting the host directory (since it's a named volume) but it's also ignoring changes to the images if you `docker-compose build` again.

You can change this `volumes:` to a bind mount, and the contents of your host system will overwrite the contents of the image.  Be careful to only mount your application source code and not your `node_modules` directory.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
# no top-level volumes:
services:
  be_server_core:
    ...
    volumes:
      - "./src:/var/be_core/src" # note path on left-hand-side
```

Rather than trying to convince Docker to simulate a local development environment, you also might find it more convenient to use an actual local development environment for day-to-day work.  Run Node and Nodemon directly on your host as normal, and bring in Docker only for your service's dependencies, and then for integration testing and deployment.  You wouldn't have a `volumes:` block at all here, your entire application would be built into the image.

Comment: nodemon --legacy-watch

Comment: nodemon --legacy-watch

Use this comment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226653/nodemon-is-not-working-in-docker-environment

Comment: A Docker container will normally run the fixed copy of the application code that's built into the image, and `nodemon` is ineffective in this environment.  To reiterate my last paragraph, the volume setup to make Docker simulate a local development environment is tricky and has often-overlooked details, and if you need `nodemon`, it will work better in a local non-Docker environment.